# How to deal with "obsolete" questions which have answers?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I observed that many of my questions either get a correct answer quite quickly (minutes to hours) or very late / never.
In the latter case, I often end up somehow working around the problem (*workaround*, not *solution*). In such a case, I'm not willed to invest more time in it to evaluate answers or comments coming in later (especially if it's long time later).

If the question is without answers, I can just delete it.
But how to deal with questions with answers which I don't judge as correct?
If I just leave them there, other people may spend time trying to answer it.
Deleting it also somehow feels wrong.

Example case: [Symfony UserBundle: override field name in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109071/symfony-userbundle-override-field-name-in-database)

Is there any best practice for such a case?

Comment: I don't understand the concern. You have an old question that has answers. If you don't think the answers solve your problem, don't accept an answer. But it's not right to delete the question just because it's old. Clearly the community has _some_ value in it.

Comment: I agree that it's not good to just delete it, that's why I ask.
On the other hand I would feel bad if 4 months later somebody comes up with a good answer which I can't validate with reasonable effort, meaning that there would be no reward for the answer.

Comment: @didi_X8 If it's a good answer that works well, they'll get rewarded in terms of upvotes. If it's a really good answer or a lot of people see it, a lot of upvotes. So don't feel too bad about that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, post your own answer explaining how you solved/got round the problem.

Make sure it is an answer - we see too many "answers" along the lines of:

> It's all solved now

or

> I did it another way

which tend to get flagged as "Not an answer" and then the moderators have to deal with the flag.

Once you've posted the answer accept it and that'll mark your question as solved.

If there's no solution then just leave the question "open". While you might have had to go a different route, someone else might have the same problem and would appreciate an answer.

Comment: In the example I linked my workaround was to not touch the Symfony-application and to change the other App using the database instead. That clearly doesn't help somebody having a similar problem and I don't think it's appropriate to make that an accepted answer.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. Is it better to mark such a workaround answer as accepted or not?

Comment: @didi_X8 - It would depend on how much of a workaround it was.